# How to download multiple images from .txt files

Tags: php, import

I got this documentation to download pictures from txt file but i have no idea how can i do this…Should i use a php script to get those pictures on my server ?

The file photos.txt is framed as follow:
- 1 line per picture (carriage return : CRLF)
- The tab key is used as a data field separator
- Column 1 : picture name indicated in the "Photos" in the data file
- Column 2 : the name of the file which should be downloaded by the partner
- Column 3 : hash key (MD5, CRC32…)

Example :

```
pc33c1_26126_08_hd.jpg /photos/pvo/transfertvo/photos/pc33c1/pc33c1_x48_08_hd.jpg 1a71ffb90de7628b8b1585b7e85c68e7
```

Example of collecting command: get « Column 2 » « Column 1 »

Example :

```
get /photos/pvo/transfertvo/photos/pc33c1/pc33c1_x48_08_hd.jpg pc33c1_26126_08_hd.jpg
```

Here is an example **data.xml** is

```
 <Photos>17125046_01_hd.jpg</Photos>
```

**photos.txt.zip**

```
17135046_01_hd.jpg /photos/xx/VO/LXZY/LXZY-1713-5642.jpg f0e533cdbaea68ab1dd52f3e7e8b3825
```

The different column are separated by "tabulation"

Both data.xml and photos.txt.zip are updated everynight and imported everynight on my server

Comment: Where do you want post the script? Computer Windows, Computer Linux, Server PHP, etc? Where?

Comment: Maybe as a php script on ftp server with an scheduled cron task ?

Answer (score 1):

I drive to this way...

In FireFox we have this Addon: [**DownThemAll**](https://addons.mozilla.org/EN-us/firefox/addon/downthemall/).

[image]
It download manager. I like and use this.

After, you can use Notepad++ to extract url.
Paste de contect file as...

[image]

After replace two times using Regular Expression

First use this regular expression: **\t[a-z0-9]*$**

[image]

Second use this regular expression: **^.*?\t**

[image]

### **Complete the url to one valid link for the internet** Example: `/photos/pvo/transfertvo/photos/pc33c1/pc33c1_x48_08_hd.jpg` to `http://www.mysite.com.br/photos/pvo/transfertvo/photos/pc33c1/pc33c1_x48_08_hd.jpg`

Finish, save file with links and open in download manager

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think that is one time forever. For automation daily... thinking...

Comment: My file Photo.txt is updated every night with new images so with your solution it will not work?

Comment: Can you post one file for example. I need to see for prove a solution.

Comment: Please look at my post, i have added more informations ! Thanks